# How to display a list on jsp page in table format

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a list in struts2 class which contains elements {a,b,c,d,e,g,h,y,t}.
i want to display this list in table format like this:

a  b  c

d  e  g

h  y  t

that means three elements per row.
i am using "s:iterator" and "s:property" tag.

Comment: is this homework ? Provide code

Comment: If it's too hard to do it in the JSP, you could do it in Java in your action, and pass this new `List<Row>` (each Row containing 1 to 3 values) to the JSP.

Comment: Thanks alli got my logic

Answer (score 0):

seems it is very easy.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <s:subset source="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" count="3" start="0">
            <s:iterator>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:subset>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <s:subset source="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" count="3" start="3">
            <s:iterator>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:subset>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <s:subset source="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" count="3" start="6">
            <s:iterator>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:subset>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

if you don't wanna use `subset`, here is the alternative.

```
<table>
    <s:iterator value="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" status="status">
        <s:if test="%{#status.index == 0}"><tr><td><s:property /></td></s:if>
            <s:elseif test="%{#status.index%3 == 0}">
            </tr><tr><td><s:property /></td>
            </s:elseif>
            <s:else>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:else>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You do like subset... But this can all be handled by checking the iterator index and doing a single numeric compare. This reduces code duplication significantly. Your example also omits the end rows and cells.

Comment: @DaveNewton hahaha... yes, you are right, but don't you think that `subset` is faster?

Comment: I doubt three subsets would be faster than a single numeric compare, but maybe. Much more confusing, too, and 3x the source.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi, here is your solution. or you got a better one.. i was just trying to help here.

Comment: I understand you're trying to help--so am I. I started with a longer comment, but then got carried away and moved it all into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is in the middle of JB's "do it on the Java side" and Jaiwo's "do it in the view".

I would favor a custom tag that takes the column count, splits the list, adds empty elements if it's not an even multiple of the column count, and wraps up all the logic in a nice little bundle.

For a view-layer only approach, I'd use a variation of either of Jaiwo's code. For the subset idea, I'd break them out into a cohesive block, but still do double-iteration–IMO this is much clearer:

```html
<s:set var="items" value="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}" />

<s:subset var="list1" source="#items" start="0" count="3" />
<s:subset var="list2" source="#items" start="3" count="3" />
<s:subset var="list3" source="#items" start="6" count="3" />

<s:set var="nested" value="{#attr.list1, #attr.list2, #attr.list3}" />

<table>
  <s:iterator value="#nested">
    <tr>
       <s:iterator>
         <td><s:property /></td>
       </s:iterator>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
```

This falls apart when the list isn't an even multiple of the column count; you can't (easily) append items to a subset (it's not a list, it's an iterator), and adding items to the original list is clumsy in JSP.

The problem with a Java-layer-only approach is that if you want to be able to set the column count from the view layer (a reasonable desire) you need to get the column count to Java. OGNL allows us to call arbitrary methods, so ultimately I'd probably implement a little utility that creates the nested lists:

```html
<s:iterator value="@utils@slice(items, 3)">
  ...
```

But I'd wrap *that* up in a custom tag, because (a) it's ugly, and (b) it clutters the mainline JSP. Similar to partials in Rails, the display of a list of objects should be refactored out, leaving:

```html
<app:showItems items="..." columns="..." />
```